# Multiple forms on one page, display one at a time with PHP if statements

Tags: php, html, forms, post, if-statement

I have five forms on one page: selectCategorySubmit, selectSoloSubmit, editSoloSubmit, selectGroupSubmit and editGroupSubmit. 
I am trying to display one at a time. When the page is opened the first form selectCategorySubmit is displayed and after it is submitted one of two thing should happen:

The selectSoloSubmit form is displayed and after it is submitted the editSoloSubmit form is displayed.

or

The selectGroupSubmit form is displayed and after it is submitted the editGroupSubmit form is displayed.

The problem I'm having is that when either the selectSoloSubmit or selectGroupSubmit form is submitted, it then goes back and displays the selectCategorySubmit form.

I have tried taking out the `if(!isset($_POST['editSoloSubmit'])) {` and `if(!isset($_POST['editGroupSubmit'])) {` if statements.

I have also tried multiple conditions for the different if statements like this:

`if(!isset($_POST['editSoloLectureSubmit']) && !isset($_POST['selectSoloBiographySubmit']) && !isset($_POST['selectCategorySubmit'])) {` but this either doesn't do anything or gives errors that selectedCategory or selectedBiography is not defined.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['selectCategorySubmit'])) {
?>

<form action="editBiography.php" method="post">
<select name="selectedCategory" size="0">
<?php getCategoryList(); ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="selectCategorySubmit" value="Select Biography Category"> 
</form>

<?php
}
else {

$selectedCategory = $_POST['selectedCategory'];

if($selectedCategory == 'Solo Exhibition') {

if(!isset($_POST['selectSoloSubmit'])) {

?>

<form action="editBiography.php" method="post">
<select name="selectedBiography" size="0">
<?php getSoloList(); ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="selectSoloSubmit" value="Select Solo Exhibition">
</form>

<?php
}
else {

if(!isset($_POST['editSoloSubmit'])) {

$selectedBiography = $_POST['selectedBiography'];

$biography = getBiographyDetails($selectedBiography);

?>

<form action="editBiography.php" method="post">
<!-- Form fields go here -->
<input type="submit" name="editSoloSubmit" value="Edit Solo Exhibition">
</form>

<?php
}
}
}

else{

if(!isset($_POST['selectGroupSubmit'])) {

?>

<form action="editBiography.php" method="post">
<select name="selectedBiography" size="0">
<?php getGroupList(); ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="selectGroupSubmit" value="Select Group Exhibition">
</form>

<?php
}
else {

if(!isset($_POST['editGroupSubmit'])) {

$selectedBiography = $_POST['selectedBiography'];

$biography = getBiographyDetails($selectedBiography);

?>    

<form action="editBiography.php" method="post">
<!-- Form fields go here -->
<input type="submit" name="editGroupSubmit" value="Edit Group Exhibition">
</form>

<?php
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: to be honest this isn't a clean method it is better to make multiple pages for each of your forms...or use javascript to make a wizard from the forms.

Comment: Just found this discuss http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/220487/benefits-of-spaghetti-code ;)

Comment: Yea, I will just put the forms on separate pages, the code won't be so complicated..